# @DataJpaTest does not recognize not null restrictions in embedded id

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to setup my db unit tests using `@DataJpaTest` annotation to avoid loading full Spring application context. But it doesn't perform the same way like when I use `@SpringBootTest` + configured H2 database. When I use H2 database I receive proper exception when trying to save entity with null id.

> JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "ID_PART_2"

But when I use DB auto-configured with use of `@DataJpaTest` as stated [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test)

> By default, it configures an in-memory embedded database, scans for @Entity classes, and configures Spring Data JPA repositories

The repository allows to insert entities with null id.

The code for my entity is:

```
package com.mycompany.test.db;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE", schema = "MY_SCHEMA")
public class MyEntity {

    //Works fine when using @Id
//    @Id
//    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
//    private String id;

    @EmbeddedId
    private MyId myId;

    @Data
    @Embeddable
    public static class MyId implements Serializable {

        //Single field reproduces the problem
//        @Column(name = "ID_PART_1", nullable = false)
//        private String idPart1;
        @Column(name = "ID_PART_2", nullable = false)
        private String idPart2;
    }
}
```

I'm using basic CRUD repository `CrudRepository<MyEntity, MyEntity.MyId>`

My tests code looks like this:

```
package com.mycompany.test.db;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest//works as expected
//@DataJpaTest//doesn't work
public class MyRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;

    private MyEntity.MyId createMyId(String part1, String part2){
        MyEntity.MyId myId = new MyEntity.MyId();
//        myId.setIdPart1(part1);
        myId.setIdPart2(part2);
        return myId;
    }

    @Test
    public void testSaveAndRead(){
        MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
        entity.setMyId(createMyId("part1", "part2"));

        repository.save(entity);
        Assert.assertNotNull(repository.findById(createMyId("part1", "part2")));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSaveWithNoPrimaryKeyFails(){
        try{
            MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
            entity.setMyId(createMyId("part1", null));
            repository.save(entity);
            Assert.fail();
        }catch(Exception expected){
            expected.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to disable DB auto-configured with use of `@DataJpaTest` by adding `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)` but it did not change anything.

**NOTE**: Problem occurs only for embedded ids. For what I see in stacktraces, in case of `javax.persistence.Id` Spring JPA fails on validation before even trying to save such entity into database.

Why the behavior is different when using `@DataJpaTest` and `@SpringBootTest`? What database is used when using `@DataJpaTest`? I think problem would be solved if Spring would use H2 in both cases, but I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you by any chance found a solution?

Comment: @PimHazebroek no, I only managed to do workaround by adding `org.junit.Before` in which I will clear database before each test manually. I'm still using `@SpringBootTest`. As an alternative, I can suggest using `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`. This way your could should be validated on java side not by DB. But of course, this depends on your needs.

**EDIT**: You might also try experiment with `org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext` but this might significantly increase time of tests.

Comment: Ah too bad, thanks for letting me know though. I'm also using @SpringBootTest instead. Don't want to reload the context unless there is absolutely no alternative. Although I'm not sure how that would solve the issue with `@DataJpaTest`. Even with a single test it already fails. Pretty worthless annotation if you'd ask me :-) but perhaps we just don't now how to use it properly ;-)

Comment: Well, I probably wasn't very clear. I meant that you might try to use `DirtiesContext` with `SpringBootTest`, so that you don't have to clear DB manually. If your tests don't take much time, this might be worth trying. [Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/DirtiesContext.html) says: _Use this annotation if a test has modified the context — for example, ... modifying the state of an embedded database_

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I just inject the repository and then clear the tables. Much faster than reloaded the context.

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by adding the line below to the test class

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```